# IE8 - Removing iframe does not stop JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, internet-explorer-8, reload

I have a window which contains iframes.

Using jquery, I remove the iframes like so:

```
var elem = $("#iframesID");
elem.empty().remove(); // overkill!
```

This always removes the iframe, however I noticed today that in IE8 the script is still running in the background. I know this, because it started throwing an error. ( `parent.something is null or not an object` )... Its almost like the page has been removed from the DOM, but the javascript is still running in the background.

I have also tried `window.location.reload()` but the script continues to run.

Any advice? Thank you

Comment: I would seriously consider your choice regarding iframes - is there a neater way to do this?

Comment: Afraid not. I'm adding to an existing project. Many iframes are used, each contains an 'individual' part of the program. iframes are not too nasty, this has just stumped me. I've put an alert in the code in the iframe now, that goes off every 20 seconds. I can remove the frame, check its gone and still the alert is fired.

Answer (score 0):

That would sound logical to me, assuming the Javascript is (called) on the parent page. My suggestion would be to first check whether an iframe is still present:

```
var elem = $("#iframesID");
if (elem) {
    elem.empty().remove(); // overkill!
}
```

or:

```
var elem = $("#iframesID");
if (!elem) {
    return;
}
else {
    elem.empty().remove(); // overkill!
}
```

My (syntax) knowledge of jQuery is not very good though, because I use native JS as good as always.